# Kendo UI data format for yearly data

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I'm pretty new to Kendo UI, and am having some trouble understanding how to format some data, and how to get it into a chart.  I have the following data as an example:

```
 var animals = [
 {
   "Animal": "Dog",
   "2017": 100,
   "2018": 120,
   "2019": 130
 },
 {
   "Animal": "Cat",
   "2017": 50,
   "2018": 40,
   "2019": 10
 },
 {
   "Animal": "Mouse",
   "2017": 10,
   "2018": 20,
   "2019": 80
 },
 {
   "Animal": "Pig",
   "2017": 40,
   "2018": 45,
   "2019": 50
 },
 {
   "Animal": "Cow",
   "2017": 80,
   "2018": 65,
   "2019": 60
 }
]
```

I want to get this data into a line chart, with the years along the x axis, and the corresponding value on the y axis.  The different animals would be represented by individual lines on the line chart.

I've searched the web for a while to find an answer to this, but haven't been able to find anything.  If anyone would be able to help me get started with this issue, or point me to a helpful tutorial, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example, it is almost what you need, but you'll need to adjust input data.
http://dojo.telerik.com/UnuSu/2

Here is how you could adjust the chart in the sample to display your data:

```
function createChart() {
    $("#chart").kendoChart({
        title: {
            text: "Your title"
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
          type: "line"
        },
        series: [{
            name: "Dog",
            data: [100, 120, 130]
        }, {
            name: "Cat",
            data: [50, 40, 10]
        }, {
            name: "Mouse",
            data: [10, 20, 80]
        },{
            name: "Pig",
            data: [40, 45, 50]
        },{
            name: "Cow",
            data: [80, 65, 60]
        }],
        categoryAxis: {
            categories: [2017, 2018, 2019]
        },
        tooltip: {
            visible: true,
            format: "{0}%",
            template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(createChart);
$(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
```

For other details regarding data-binding, charts configuration see reference:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/charts/overview

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/charts/overview#see-also

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16353460)

Comment: @Dev-iL Thanks! Updated the post.

Comment: @sasha_gud - this is exactly the right type of response to a review comment. Well done.